# Is the energy needed to extract an electron from a high density plasma greater than the ionization energy?

Tags: energy, charge, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

Now, imagine I have only one particle or atom. Now I give it some energy,which equals the ionization energy.The electron in the outer shell is now at infinity. But If I have a Gas(a large number of atoms) and not just one atom, since I provide all of them with energy at the same time, all the particles affect each other. Now, I try to pull out electrons in the outermost shells by supplying the gas with energy, which equals the number of atoms multiplied by the ionization energy. But since there are many more positive nucleus', the attraction is higher and at the same time there are also many negative charges that repel each other. So, can I pull out the outer shell electrons of all the atoms with the supplied energy or will I need more energy??

To sum it all up
--Is the energy needed to extract an electron from a high density plasma greater than the ionization energy?

Comment: I think this would depend upon how you are depositing energy, the velocity distribution of the neutral gas, and which element is receiving the energy.  However, I am fairly confident that you will need more energy than the minimum threshold estimate to liberate electrons from all of them.